# jQuery splash screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transitions, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a jquery splash screen, I've found a perfect tutorial here: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/ but need some help on modifying the script.

Currently if you view it here: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/ the text images above the apple image change but I would like to add several images that fade in one after the other but also remain on the screen, unlike the current script in the tutorial it fades in one image and fades out i would like to fade in image#1 wait 2 sec fade in img #2 and so on but keeping each image on the screen.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

A small help

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Thanks, however I need to disect this code below and figure out how to add fade in and fade out for individual images, I want to fade in an image, keep it visable and fade in another one, at a different position, sort of like a random loading of images.

Comment: you can give id to the images or put images in div tag and use their ids. you can also use .slideToggle() . Am not sure you can use it in your case or not.As a new user shall i tell you something you should always appreciate the people if their answers or comments are helpful to you. Gotcha? :-)